# UITableview custom section view move to the top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableview` where I use `view` for header for section method to customize the `view` like a drop down so that,when I select the particular `button` on the section header view the `cell` for `row` appears,like a drop down.I need in a way such that when I select the particular `section` this `section` should go to the top of the `tableview`. Is there a solution to implement this.

Comment: try this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: use "scrollToRowAtIndexPath" of UItableview , this will scroll the selected section at top